# Thinking in C++ Exercise

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and I'm following the "Thinking in C++" book, I'm doing the exercises and I can't understand why in this exercise:

> Define an array of `int`. Take the starting address of that array and use `static_cast` to convert it into an `void*`. Write a function that takes a `void*`, a number (indicating a number of bytes), and a value (indicating the value to which each byte should be set) as arguments. The function should set each byte in the specified range to the specified value. Try out the function on your array of `int`.

this solution works

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PR(EX) cout << #EX << ": " << EX << endl;

void f1( void* v, size_t num_bytes, int val){

  unsigned char* p_addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(v);
  unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(val);

  for( size_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++){
    *p_addr = byte++;
    p_addr++;
  }

  PR(num_bytes);

}

int main(){

  int a[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  int value = 67;
  void* vp = static_cast<void*>(&a);    

  f1(vp, sizeof(a), value);

  unsigned char* byte = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(vp);


  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++){
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
    for( int j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++){
      cout << reinterpret_cast<int*>(*byte) << " ";
      byte++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

while this one does not

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PR(EX) cout << #EX << ": " << EX << endl;

void f1( void* v, size_t num_bytes, int val){

  unsigned char* p_addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(v);
  unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(val);

  for( size_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++){
    *p_addr = byte++;
    p_addr++;
  }

  PR(num_bytes);

}

int main(){

  int a[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  int value = 67;
  void* vp = static_cast<void*>(&a);
  unsigned char* byte = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(vp);

  for( size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])); i++){
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
    for( size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++){
       cout << *byte;
       byte++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  PR(*byte);


  f1(vp, sizeof(a), value);    

  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++){
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
    for( int j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++){
      cout << reinterpret_cast<int*>(*byte) << " ";
      byte++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

The differences are in where i define the pointer `byte`, in the "working" version it is before the function call while in the "not working" version it is before. The `cout` of the two versions are

```
a[0] = 
a[1] = 
a[2] = 
a[3] = 
a[4] = 
*byte: 
num_bytes: 20
a[0] = 0 0 0 0 
a[1] = 0x3b 0x8 0x40 0 
a[2] = 0 0 0 0 
a[3] = 0x4 0 0 0 
a[4] = 0 0 0 0
```

and

```
num_bytes: 20
a[0] = 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x46 
a[1] = 0x47 0x48 0x49 0x4a 
a[2] = 0x4b 0x4c 0x4d 0x4e 
a[3] = 0x4f 0x50 0x51 0x52 
a[4] = 0x53 0x54 0x55 0x56
```

in the second one i thing that byte are changing in the right way, while in the first one it seems to me that something is going wrong. Apparently the issue is on where i define the `byte` pointer and, since I'm a beginner and learning by myself, I wish to understand what I'm thinking wrong.

Ok, I've understood my error thanks to you suggestions, I've modified the code and now it prints what I was expecting

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PR(EX) cout << #EX << ": " << EX << endl;

void f1( void* v, size_t num_bytes, int val){

  unsigned char* p_addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(v);
  unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(val);

  for( size_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++){
    *p_addr = byte++;
    p_addr++;
  }

  PR(num_bytes);

}

int main(){

  int a[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  int value = 67;
  void* vp = static_cast<void*>(a);
  unsigned char* byte = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(vp);

  for( size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])); i++){
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
    for( size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++){
      cout << reinterpret_cast<int*>(*byte);
      byte++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  byte = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(vp);

  f1(vp, sizeof(a), value);

  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++){
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
    for( int j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++){
      cout << *byte << " ";
      byte++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;

}

a[0] = 0000
a[1] = 0000
a[2] = 0000
a[3] = 0000
a[4] = 0000
num_bytes: 20
a[0] = C D E F 
a[1] = G H I J 
a[2] = K L M N 
a[3] = O P Q R 
a[4] = S T U V
```

Comment: Point out the difference. Also, what does "not work" mean?  What happens?

Comment: Do you really expect us to compare those two programs line by line? And, yeah, what does it mean when you say "it doesn't not work"?

Comment: None of the programs work as per the specification: You increase `byte` each iteration in the loop, while the spec says that each byte should be set to the same value.

Comment: Also, you cast the address of the array pointer, which results in you calling the function with a pointer to a pointer. Skip the ampersand in the `static_cast`.

Comment: Please describe exactly what the problem is. "Does not work" is not helping anyone or you. When you've explained why it doesn't work then please flag to re-open.

Comment: The differences are, in the "not working" version i put the definition of the byte pointer before the call to the function f1, while in the "working" version it is defined after the function.
By "not working" i mean that when i cout the "not working" version it seems that the function doesen't change the byte as expected while in the "working" version it happens what i expected.
Sorry for not being clear before, let me know if I'm not helping you helping me.

Comment: While printing out your array, you iteratively increment the `byte` value, until it reaches the byte next to the end of your array. So your second print is incorrect. You should reset the `byte` value before each printing.

Comment: In the second version you don't call f1 before printing the values. That's why it looks like f1 hasn't been called when you print the values. There are other problems as well which are shared by both versions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i know that I'm increasing 'byte' after each iteration, I did it on purpose, also i thought that putting the ampersand or not is indifferent, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. The data of the array can be placed in one place in memory, while the pointer (`a` in this case) will be somewhere else. This means that `a` will point to the array, while `&a` will point to variable `a` and not the array.

Comment: Ok it seems I'm getting closer to understand my error, if i print the values of `byte` and `a`, I expected to be the same because `byte` and `a` both share the same adress but it turns out I'm thinking wrong. Is there an issue in casting an array of `int` into an `usigned char`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pointer to print the array values and your printing loop advances the pointer. **In your second code listing you fail to reset the pointer to the beginning of the array.** Your second loop prints values well past the end of the array.

Edit:

In your first loop you are printing `*byte` which is interpreted as a 8-bit character value. The array is initialized to all zeros which aren't printable ASCII values. If you want to print the numeric value then change `*byte` to `static_cast<int>(*byte)`.

In your second loop your `reinterpret_cast<int*>(*byte)` tries to reinterpret an unsigned char as a pointer to int. I don't think that's what you meant to do. You should change that to `static_cast<int>(*byte)` like the first loop. Alternately, because your function has filled the array with valid ASCII character codes the the second loop could just send `*byte` to cout.

My changes to your code and the output can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/IpZEA)

Comment: Thanks, i think we get the solution at the same time, i posted the corrected code, thanks for the help and the suggestions!